# Get current authenticated user in Cassandra CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cassandra-2.0

I am implementing a row-level security mechanism in Apache Cassandra.  Therefore, I am looking to retrieve the login name of the current authenticated user in Cassandra (similar to the SUSER_NAME variable in SQL Server).  Any thoughts?

Best,

Tom

Comment: Just looked through the source of `cqlsh`, and I don't think it's possible right now.  It'd be nice if it had a `whoami` for that. https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/bin/cqlsh